# Case expression for null and not null columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentScore (
    Student_ID INT,
    Student_Name NVARCHAR (50),
    Student_Score INT) 
GO

INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (1,'Ali', NULL)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (4,NULL, 770)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (5,'John', 1240)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (6,'Mike', 1140)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (7,'Goerge', NULL)
```

Query tried

```
select * from StudentScore
Select TYPE1 =
CASE WHEN ANY(SELECT COLUMN IS NULL) THEN 'AT least 1 NULL'
    ELSE 'NON-NULL'
END
```

Basically I want that if there is any single null bvalue for any column in table StudentScore, then the type of that column should be null else it should be not null (note that this is part of interview question and I cannot use `information_schema` etc. I need to do this using case. Can anyone help

For e.g. here ID will be NON-NULL, rest two will be type 'At least 1 null'

EDIT after seeing answers to clarify:

I want that my code should check all rows of columns and return 'Non-null' if all the rows in a column are not null.
All the columns should be checked individually.

For e.g. this code gives output as below:

```
select case when Student_Score is null then 'non-null'
else 'non-null'
end TYPE1 from StudentScore

TYPE1
non-null
non-null
non-null
non-null
non-null
non-null
non-null
```

**The above is not my desired output**.

**My desired output is**

**Not null columns**: ID
,**At least 1 null value** (in all the rows corresponding to one column): Student_Score, Student_name.

So the **code should return 'at least 1 null value' if for a particular column, there is at least one null value present in all the rows** .

**For e.g. it should check all 8 rows corresponding to each column and if there is no null value in all rows corresponding to one column, then only that column is going to 'Not null'**

**Also I removed primary key to make question more generic.**

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular form

Comment: No need to check for `NULL` in `Student_ID` as it is primary key. Primary key columns can never contain `NULL` (at least in SQL Server) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to put this into separate columns:

```
select (case when count(*) = count(student_id) then 'No Null Values' else 'Null Values' end) as student_id,
       (case when count(*) = count(student_name) then 'No Null Values' else 'Null Values' end) as student_name,
       (case when count(*) = count(student_score) then 'No Null Values' else 'Null Values' end) as student_score
from studentscores;
```

This should be the simplest and most performance way to do what you want.

If you want this in separate rows, I would just unpivot these results:

```
select v.*
from (select (case when count(*) = count(student_id) then 'No Null Values' else 'Null Values' end) as student_id,
             (case when count(*) = count(student_name) then 'No Null Values' else 'Null Values' end) as student_name,
             (case when count(*) = count(student_score) then 'No Null Values' else 'Null Values' end) as student_score
      from studentscores
     ) ss cross apply
     (values ('student_id', student_id), ('student_name', student_name), ('student_score', student_score)
     ) v(col, str)
```

Comment: this is best answer

Comment: No it is not. Exists outperforms aggregation in any case.

Comment: @forpas . . . That might be true when there is a `group by` clause.  However, aggregation with a single row does not require sorting or partitioning the data, so it is usually pretty efficient.

Comment: Each of `case when count(*) = count(...)` performs aggregation by scanning the full table, while `case when exists(...)` does not aggregate and returns as soon as it finds what it is looking for. The difference is obvious.

Comment: @forpas . . . That is not how databases work.  The table should be scanned only once.

Comment: This is what I said: a full table scan with aggregation on all columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the all columns operator (*)  in this case
you could try using a case when with OR condition for each explicit named column

```
    select case when col1 is null 
            OR col2 is null 
            OR  col3 is NULL then 'AT least 1 NULL'
            ELSE 'NON-NULL' END type
    from StudentScore
```

in your case

```
    select Student_ID, Student_Name, Student_Score
    , case when Student_Name is null 
                OR Student_Score is null 
                then 'AT least 1 NULL'
                ELSE 'NON-NULL' END type
        from StudentScore
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.  please re read the editted question to understand my problem statement better.

Comment: i have liked your answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want 1 row and 1 column as result, so you can use EXISTS:

```
select 
  case 
    when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Name is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL'
    when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Score is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL'
    else 'NON-NULL'
  end TYPE1
```

or:

```
select 
  case 
    when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Name is null)
    or exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Score is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL'
    else 'NON-NULL'
  end TYPE1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cba068e3b61fc79ed3c8b39b13e95ffc).
Result:

```
> | TYPE1           |
> | :-------------- |
> | AT least 1 NULL |
```

If you want 1 result for each of the columns:

```
select 
  case when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_ID is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL' else 'NON-NULL' end ID,
  case when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Name is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL' else 'NON-NULL' end Student_Name,
  case  when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Score is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL' else 'NON-NULL' end Student_Score
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3116bbca44426c87c33a3de407859f64).
Results:

```
> ID       | Student_Name    | Student_Score  
> :------- | :-------------- | :--------------
> NON-NULL | AT least 1 NULL | AT least 1 NULL
```

Or if you want 2 rows, 1 for each type and the column names as a comma separated list:

```
select type, string_agg(colname, ',') columns
from (
  select 'id' colname, case when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_ID is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL' else 'NON-NULL' end type
  union all
  select 'Student_Name', case when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Name is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL' else 'NON-NULL' end
  union all
  select 'Student_Score', case when exists (select 1 from StudentScore where Student_Score is null) then 'AT least 1 NULL' else 'NON-NULL' end
) t
group by type
```

This code works for SQL Server 2017+.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d56b4ace924a4decbd97b265c9bdd0f).
Results:

```
> type            | columns                   
> :-------------- | :-------------------------
> AT least 1 NULL | Student_Name,Student_Score
> NON-NULL        | id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.  please re read the editted question to understand my problem statement better.